# Bash - removing characters other than specific string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, kernel

I use `wget -O` to get the site text to a specific file.

It saves the file within ONE line. File has about 2 milion characters. After, I would like to remove any other characters different from `"directory= ************"` format (including quotation mark, `****` stand for any text till second quotation mark).

Is there any smart way to acomplish that?

Comment: try to use sed  http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -o '"directory= [^"]*"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The smartest way would be to pipe it out to a smarter interpreter. Python for instance.

Python has a great [regular expressions library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) at your disposal.